# Update script to search and replace using a Lookup Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table with floor names that I need to replace with numerical values.  I'm building a lookup table by hand. Not sure what to do next... Is there a better way?

Screenshot: http://i49.tinypic.com/2mc921e.png

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- lookup table
DECLARE @FloorLkup TABLE(
    FloorName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    FloorNum INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @FloorLkup SELECT 'First floor', '1'
INSERT INTO @FloorLkup SELECT 'First', '1'
INSERT INTO @FloorLkup SELECT 'Second floor', '2'
INSERT INTO @FloorLkup SELECT 'Second', '2'
-- etc.
INSERT INTO @FloorLkup SELECT 'Ninth', '9'

print 'Done'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
print 'Did not work'
ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Also, problem is: some floors are named `First` and `First floor`, etc.

Comment: Can you show the structure and data you need to fix?

Comment: @AaronBertrand See http://i49.tinypic.com/2mc921e.png  What else do you need to know?

Comment: Well, do you want to put the number in the `FloorName` column, or do you want to add a new numeric column, update that, and later drop the `FloorName` column? I recommend the latter. It allows you to check your work before committing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  Hmm, yes.  The latter is the better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- populate your @FloorLkup table here

-- now add a new numeric column:
ALTER TABLE dbo.UnknownTableName
  ADD FloorNumber INT;

-- now update based on matches in @FloorLkup
UPDATE t
  SET FloorNumber = fl.FloorNum
  FROM dbo.UnknownTableName AS t
  INNER JOIN @FloorLkup AS fl
  ON t.FloorName = fl.FloorName;

-- check your work
SELECT * FROM dbo.UnknownTableName;

-- if it's correct:
ALTER TABLE dbo.UnknownTableName
  DROP COLUMN FloorName;
```

You'll have to replace `UnknownTableName` with the name of your destination table, since you forgot to tell us. You may also need to remove any constraints or other explicit references to the `FloorName` column before you can drop it.

Also please don't be afraid of vowels or longer names. `Lookup` and `FloorNumber` are actually a *LOT* easier to type than `Lkup` and `FloorNum`.